how to improve get media url from publicId in cloudinary php-sdk
We use php-sdk cloudinary.
we want to fetch image links based on publicId. but it's a bit slow. is there any way to improve it or use another solution?
this function is a bit slow.
Media::fromParams($publicId, $options)->toUrl();



try using the class Cloudinary\Tag\ImageTag.
Here's a sample snippet: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_quickstart#4_transform_and_deliver_the_image
